# jQuery delegate with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, delegates

In a jQuery Mobile project I would like to set the login form to not use ajax.
The forms ID is UserLoginForm and the following is apparently wrong:

```
jQuery('#UserLoginForm').delegate('form', 'submit', function(){
    jQuery('#UserLoginForm').jqmData('ajax', false);
});
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery('#UserLoginForm').delegate('input[type="submit"]', 'submit', function(){
    jQuery('#UserLoginForm').jqmData('ajax', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add attribute in the form tag
like this

```
data-ajax="false"
```